# Building loading div by js

Tags: javascript

I want to build a loading div. Its width should grow in 0,01s of 1% his width.

My code:

```
const btn = document.querySelector('button');
const div = document.querySelector('div');
div.style.width = `0%`;


const loading = () => {

let divWidth = 0;

function load() {
    divWidth++;
    div.style.width = `${divWidth}%`;
}

if (divWidth <= 100) {
    setTimeout(load, 100);
}

};

btn.addEventListener('click', loading);
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('button');
const div = document.querySelector('div');
div.style.width = "0%";
var divWidth = 0;

function a() {
  divWidth++;
  // console.log(divWidth)
  div.style.width = `${divWidth}%`;
  if (divWidth <= 100) {
    setTimeout(a, 100);
  }
}
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid yellow;
  background-color:purple;
  color:white;
}
```

```html
<div>loading....</div>
<button onclick="a()">click</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use setInterval instead of setTimeout

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('button');
const div = document.querySelector('div');
div.style.width = `0%`;


const loading = () => {
  let divWidth = 0;

  function load() {
      divWidth++;
      div.style.width = `${divWidth}%`;
      if(divWidth >= 100) clearInterval(loader);
  }

  const loader = setInterval(load, 100);
};

btn.addEventListener('click', loading);
```

```css
.growing-div {
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<button>Button</button>
<div class="growing-div">Div</div>
```